# android connect to server instead of localhost from mobile instead of emulator

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator

I have built an Android application using the emulator to test.  It connects to `localhost` to get and send data which works well.  Now I want to try that application on my mobile device.  I have read that I have to:

1. connect my computer to my router network
2. connect my mobile to my router network
3. go to the code and replace the `10.0.2.2` with the IP of my computer

Am I right?  If so, is that computer's IP the IP that connects my computer to internet?

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing in Eclipse, all you have to do is:

1. Connect your device to your computer with a USB cable
2. Right click on the root of your app
3. Select "Run As" > Android Application
4. If your device is connected, it should automatically run

*Note* sometimes you have to select whether you run on your connected device or on your emulator, but a window will display your options and your just select one.

Simple as that.

Comment: i don't want to connect using `cable`, i want to connect using `local network`

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to connect using a cable?

Comment: my graduation project is a server/client project, i will test the project using 5 mobile devices

Comment: and i tried your way but eclipse run the application on emulator, not on mobile, have i make any configurations?

Comment: Right click on the Root (after you connect via cable) and select "Run As" > Run Configurations, click on the Target tab, then select "manual". If your device is connected, you will get a prompt asking you to connect either to your device or emulator when your follow the above steps. If that doesn't work your device might not be recognized by your computer. To test that, go into DDMS and see if your device is recognized. If not, try a different cable or check your connection settings.

Comment: when i select manual, i didn't get any results, how can i go to DDMS please, i have just bought the device so the cable is working

Comment: Window > Open Perspective > Other > DDMS

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13384/discussion-between-blaine-anderson-and-totti-roma)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, when you simply connect to your local router you can get to your localhost by changing the configuration to point to: "http://10.0.2.2:8080"

I found the other ways to be very tedious

http://juristr.com/blog/2009/10/accessing-host-machine-from-your/
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: i will check your solution after i finish connect my device to my computer, thank you

Comment: Not really MY solution, it was a solution that the android engineers developed. :) Anyways, happy programming and I hope it works out for you as it did for me.